# Biasing using constant current source

Tags: mosfet, cmos, nmos

[image]

guys i was going through this diagram in my book when these lines came along(i am a student):
*Here R<sub>G</sub>(usually in M-ohm range) establishes a dc ground at the gate and presents a large resistance to input signal.....* I want to ask why resistor is used? can't we directly ground it?

Comment: Where are the input and output ports in your circuit? If input is applied to the gate, you can't short circuit it to ground because that would short out the input and result in no signal transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly ground the Gate, sort of.

The Gate is where the input signal is applied. If you have a direct short from Gate to ground, the signal is shorted to ground and there isn't anything to amplify.

**BUT**

If your signal source has DC continuity, you can connect it between Gate and ground without any problems.

This signal source might be a transformer or inductor or similar. The DC continuity provides the bias path that the FET requires.

Comment: Reid, please tell me where can i learn mosfets in a simple and interesting way. Pls! i wish to become good at it. your reputation says you did.